# What is the pricing tier of google sign-in?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, google-authentication, google-identity

There is a note in google identity platform document:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect

Note: If you want to provide a "Sign-in with Google" button for your website or app, we recommend using Google Sign-In, our sign-in client library that is built on the OpenID Connect protocol and provides OpenID Connect formatted ID Tokens.

As I understand, google using OpenID Connect for sign-in library, which means the pricing tier for this is tier 2 according to this page:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing

and I will have to pay if there are more than 50 people sign in to my site each month,
Please help me to confirm if this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sign-In and Identity Platform are two separate products (although they can be used in combination).

If you're just using Google Sign-In [as described in the OpenID Connect docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect), then the Identity Platform pricing doesn't apply.

Comment: Everything related to authentication is on one page: https://developers.google.com/identity/authentication. And there is a price for that services https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing